# how to fetch data through multiple account with threading in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I want to achieve a function that can fetch data in parallel.

The background is the information of 100 sites can be fetched from site A.

the same account can't be used more than once at a time, so I created 5 different accounts on site A that eanble me to fetch information with 5 accounts.

account info like

```
worker1 pawd
worker2 pawd
worker3 pawd
worker4 pawd
worker5 pawd
```

if you want to get information of site B from site A .
then you need to type cmd like `get info for siteB_IP` on site A.

suppose there are 100 IPs are stored in a list names `IPlist`

how to fetch information of 100 IPs with 5 avaliable accounts in parallel by threading , and then
all of the information can be sotored in a variable without conflict.

what I have tried is below , below codes can not be executed due to I have no way to achieve the solution:

```
import threading

user = 'root'
pwd = 'Changeme123'
# the first step is to logon with default account
rs = link.send_cmd(r':lognew:' + '"' + user + '","' + pwd + '"')
# then get all nebor ip from the logon site, the function parse_multi is used for parsing data
IPlist = parse_multi(link.send_cmd('get-IP-info:0xffff'))

def Fetchinfo(user, ip):
    rs = link.send_cmd(r':lognew:' + '"' + user + '","' + pwd + '"')
    areainfo = link.send_cmd('get info for ' + site_IP)


for ip in IPlist:
    # how to handle 100 IPs in the situstion of 5 accounts avaliable ?    
    thread = threading.thread(target = Fetchinfo, args = [worker, ip]
```

Comment: you can refer to my answer for batching the IPs for each account to retrieve and then using a pool of threads for each account to use each account concurrently to fetch their corresponding batch of IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want calls from the same account id and passwords to happen concurrently, you can define a function that sequentially loops through a sub-list of IPs to fetch synchronously:

```
def fetch_data_for_ips(account_id, account_password, ips_to_fetch):
    results = list()
    for ip_to_fetch in ips_to_fetch:
        # fetch with the account_id and password synchronously
        result = ...
        results.append(result)
    return results // Added this
```

Then, use a thread pool, to run the different batches concurrently for each account:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

# Split the workload for each account to fetch
num, remainder = divmod(len(ip_list), len(accounts))
num_ips_for_each_account = num + bool(remainder)

# This gives e.g. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], where each sublist is for each account to fetch
ip_lists_for_each_account = [ip_list[i: i + num_ips_for_each_account] for i in range(0, len(ip_list), num_ips_for_each_account)]


# You should only need number of threads = to the number of accounts you have
with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(accounts)) as executor:
    # Feel free to use a set instead if you don't need to know which result came from which thread
    futures = dict()
    results = list()

    for (account_id, account_password), ips_to_fetch in zip(accounts, ip_lists_for_each_account):
        future = executor.submit(fetch_data_for_ips, account_id, account_password, ips_to_fetch)
        futures[future] = account_id

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        account_id = futures[future]
        print(f'{account_id} fetched these:', result)

        results.extend(result)
```

Comment: thanks rcshon, I am trying your suggestion now , since there is no return value from function `fetch_data_for_ips`, is `results` a shared variable ?

Comment: No it was not intended to be shared. I meant to return it from the function so that `future.result()` gets it returned. I've updated the code to include the return statement in the function.

Comment: Rcshon, I think your solution can fix my issue , but it seems that the workload hasn't been split to each worker , the fact is that  I created 5 workers to fetch information for 2 IPs, the programe assigned 2 wokers to work as expected , but worker1 fetches information for 2 IPs as well as woker2 does , I think the expected result is worker1 fetches information for one IP and worker2 does the same for another one .

Comment: That should be the behavior by the answer I provided. Perhaps you are missing something, which I can't tell.

Comment: yes, I know the reason , that's becasue I messed up `ip_list` and `ips_to_fetch `, in the row `future = executor.submit(fetch_data_for_ips, account_id, account_password, ip_list)` the `ip_list` should be instead of `ips_to_fetch ` as you required

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to below sample code as rcshon suggested .

```
def fetch_data_for_ips(account_id,ips_to_fetch):
    results = list()
    for ip_to_fetch in ips_to_fetch:
        # fetch with the account_id and password synchronously
        result = ','.join((account_id,ip_to_fetch))
        results.append(result)
    return results

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
accounts = ['worker1','worker2','worker3','worker4','worker5']
ip_list = [str(_) for _ in range(10)]

# Split the workload for each account to fetch
num, remainder = divmod(len(ip_list), len(accounts))
num_ips_for_each_account = num + bool(remainder)

# This gives e.g. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], where each sublist is for each account to fetch
ip_lists_for_each_account = [ip_list[i: i + num_ips_for_each_account] for i in range(0, len(ip_list), num_ips_for_each_account)]

# You should only need number of threads = to the number of accounts you have
with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(accounts)) as executor:
    # Feel free to use a set instead if you don't need to know which result came from which thread
    futures = dict()
    results = list()

    for account_id, ips_to_fetch in zip(accounts, ip_lists_for_each_account):
        future = executor.submit(fetch_data_for_ips, account_id, ips_to_fetch)
        futures[future] = account_id

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        account_id = futures[future]
        print(f'{account_id} fetched these:', result)

        results.extend(result)

output :
worker3 fetched these: ['worker3,4', 'worker3,5']
worker2 fetched these: ['worker2,2', 'worker2,3']
worker1 fetched these: ['worker1,0', 'worker1,1']
worker4 fetched these: ['worker4,6', 'worker4,7']
worker5 fetched these: ['worker5,8', 'worker5,9']
```